# Generate a table with columns using multiple encodings

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, character-encoding

In e.g. mysql you can do something like

```
CREATE TABLE tags
(
  tag_name VARCHAR(10)  CHARACTER SET latin1,
  tag_desc VARCHAR(140) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
);
```

Is there any way to get SQLAlchemy to generate a table like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was actually able to figure this out myself.  Instead of using the generic types like

```
sqlalchemy.types.String(length = 10)
```

I just have to use

```
sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.VARCHAR(length = 10, charset = 'latin1')
```